# Should I delete samples from the training data that are present in the testing data by accident?

Tags: train-test-split, data-leakage

I classify pairs of entities, let's say dog-cat pairs, whether there is association between them (positive class) or there is not (negative class). I have a moderately sized positive dataset (~130k pairs) to which I use negative sampling to create the same number of negative pairs by randomly recombining the dogs and cats to pairs that are not present in the positive set.

I also have a very small (~600 pairs) test data with both positive and negative pairs. Now my problem is that I've noticed that around 120 positive pairs of the testing dataset are present in the initial positive dataset of 130k as well. Given how small the testing set is, I can observe visible changes in the performance of the model depending on whether I manually delete these entries from the training data or not. What would be the correct way of handling this? Feels like cheating to leave them in. On the other hand, the two datasets are from entirely different sources and the testing set is a fairly common benchmark set.

There are, of course, also "accidental hits" with the random negative samples that match with samples from the testing set, which I don't intend to manually delete. I'd argue that those matching samples are a beneficial result of the negative sampling approach. I'm not sure whether something similar could be stated for the positive matching samples.

Comment: I think this is questionable relative to the generalizability of the model, in particular when the duplicates represent such a proportion of the test set. Imagine if all the observations in the test set were already present in the training set; it would not matter if the two sets were collected independently. Now, is there a reason why you don't merge the train and test sets, remove the duplicates, and then conduct crossvalidation on the resulting dataset? You could also consider using a resampling method for validation instead of data splitting, see https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val

Comment: @J-J-J I used the larger positive (+negative sampled) dataset to train and cross-validate, while searching for optimal hyperparameters. Now that it is over, I trained the model on the entire train set and I want to test it on the small, independent test set, which is considered to be an accepted benchmark dataset. In the cases I've seen, people either didn't bother to filter the training data by it, or they presented results for both filtered and unfiltered training. The question is, which is the most correct way?

Comment: My suggestion was to merge the train and test datasets, remove the duplicates, and start all over from the beginning (including the search for optimal parameters and such). But now that you've peeked at the data and tried some models, that could introduce bias in the process, making my suggestion hazardous. Maybe other people will have better suggestions. But regardless of this suggestion being relevant or not, I think it's problematic to have the same observations in the test and train sets, in particular as these duplicates represent a large proportion of the test set.